# What animated movie had reptilian aliens attacking a city surrounded by a force field?

Tags: story-identification

I think I watched this movie back in 1994-1995. It was on two VHS tapes, I remember that. Overall the animation felt like superhero cartoons from the 80's. It was a Russian dub, but the original language was English.

There was a city protected entirely by a force field shield, and bad guys were constantly attacking it but couldn't penetrate the shield. The whole movie was futuristic and they used some kind of flying cars for warfare/travel. I think the whole setting was on another planet.

The main cast of characters had super powers. One of the good guys had power to become invisible and walk through walls.

The bad guys were race of alien reptile-like creatures, and had a warrior that had a flamethrower installed into his mouth. He had tubes connected to his cheeks that supplied fuel for flamethrower and were attached to his fuel tank he was carrying.

Comment: This sounds similar to [Final Fantasy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0173840/) but it was released on 2001. Also, no superpowers that I remember.

Comment: It's definitely not final fantasy as the overall movie felt like something made in late 80's

Comment: [Sky Blue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B6PQ9HDLSkE) seems to fit lot of the description, but again the year is all wrong, 2003 not 1994; http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0353014/

Comment: I've watched Sky Blue and no it's not it, the thing I'm talking about overall felt like 80's superheroes animation movie

Comment: What language was the movie in?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite it was a Russian DUB but original language was English

Comment: Was it definitely a film? Could it have been a feature length episode of an anime series?

Comment: @maguirenumber6 might be, also it didn't felt like anime, more like american tv series

Comment: 2 VHS tapes for an animated movie sounds inordinately long. Any possibility it was a short series of episodes rather than a single movie?

Comment: @milonaut probably, I remember we had to switch VHS to continue watching

Answer (score 1):

[The Shrunken City](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0156075/)

From IMDB: "Two teen-aged kids discover a miniature bottled city buried beneath a construction site. They must protect the tiny civilization within from reptilian alien hunters after its everlasting power supply."

The baddies had tech which let them appear human but do alien things.

Things which match:

- The city is bottled, and the perimeter is a force-field.
- It's tremendously 80s

Things which don't match:

- I don't remember any flying cars
- it's not on another planet
- it's not animated!

Comment: yeah I've checked it, it's not that but thanks anyway